# Reading DateTime column gives DetachedInstanceError after session is closed

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'd like to access a field called `timeCreated` on a mapped object. The field is instantiated via a `utcnow()` FunctionElement (taken from this [example](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/compiler.html?highlight=utcnow#utc-timestamp-function)).

After doing a `merge` or `add` call, committing, then closing the session, I've noticed that I get the below error when accessing the field. I have `expire_on_commit` set to False.

```
sqlalchemy.orm.exc.DetachedInstanceError: Instance <User at 0x102046710> is not bound to a Session; attribute refresh operation cannot proceed (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/13/bhk3)
```

Example code:

```py
def write(obj):
    with sessionScope() as session:
        obj.timeCreated = utcnow()
        ret = session.merge(obj)
    return ret

user = User(name='Totoro')
savedUser = write(user)

# Error occurs when accessing timeCreated
print(savedUser.timeCreated)
```

SessionScope() is taken from [these docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/session_basics.html?highlight=yield%20session), it's defined as:

```
sessionFactory = sessionmaker(bind=engine)

@contextmanager
def sessionScope():
    try:
        session = sessionFactory()
        yield session
        session.commit()
    except Exception as e:
        session.rollback()
        raise
    finally:
        session.close()
    return
```

Is there a reason why timeCreated is not resolved after `commit()`? If, after committing, but before closing, I access `timeCreated`, then subsequent accesses after `close` still work.

Is there a way to "eager" load this type of column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when `timeCreated` is assigned to the result of calling `utcnow`, SQLAlchemy doesn't assign the result from the server immediately; instead a placeholder value is assigned, as we can see in the debugger:

```
(Pdb) obj.__dict__
{..., 'timeCreated': <__main__.utcnow at 0x7f237d0a90a0; utcnow object>}
```

When the session is closed, this placeholder value is expired:

```
(Pdb) sa.inspect(savedUser).expired_attributes
{'timeCreated'}
```

So, as stated at the end of the question, the value of `timeCreated` must be loaded before the session is closed to prevent a `DetachedInstanceError` if it is accessed later.

Based on the documentation for [Fetching Server-Generated Defaults (case 1)](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/persistence_techniques.html#case-1-non-primary-key-returning-or-equivalent-is-supported),  this can be done by by setting `timeCreated`'s  `server_default` attribute to a [FetchedValue](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/defaults.html#sqlalchemy.schema.FetchedValue), and setting `eager_defaults` to `True` in the mapper args.

Here is an example model (tested on Mariadb and Postgresql):

```
from sqlalchemy.schema import FetchedValue


class User(Base):
    ...
    timeCreated = Column(DateTime, server_default=FetchedValue())

    __mapper_args__ = {'eager_defaults': True}
```

For what it's worth, setting `server_default=utcnow()` in combination with the mapper args would work just as well, and avoid the need to set `timeCreated` explicitly; but perhaps the OP has their own reason for doing this.